# Specify cmath's pow function and not locally declared one

Tags: c++, methods, overloading, pow

When calling `ans+= c[i] * pow(x,i);`, xCode is complaining "Too many arguements to function call, expected 1 have 2".  I have a locally defined function as follows:

```
    Polynomial pow(unsigned int n) const;
```

and a constructor:

```
    Polynomial(const double t = 0.0);
```

How can I specify that I would like to use cmath's pow function and not the locally defined one?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, assuming you're keeping all your own stuff out of the `std` namespace (and, if you're not, you *should* be, since that was the entire *raison d'être* of namespaces), you can just use `std::pow()`.

See the following code for an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int pow(int x, int y) { return -1; }
int main() {
    std::cout << std::pow(3,2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That fails.  XCode says that std doesn't have a member called pow.

Comment: Then XCode is broken or you're including `math.h` instead of `cmath`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by "locally defined" you mean a member of a class, since ordinarily function overloading would be able to tell the difference between the two functions; a class member will hide a similarly named function at global scope.

Just use `::pow` if you can't change the name of the locally defined function.